# Jpa many to many relation, bad sql query generated

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a lodger object who have possibility to have many contact. Same contact can be associated to many lodger. It's a many to many relation.

In lodger i have,

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "lodger")
private List<Contact> contactList;
```

In contact, I have

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "lodger_contact", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lodger_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id"))
private List<Lodger> lodger;
```

I use spring-jpa data. Jpa implementation used is hibernate

In my Contact repository interface, i created this method

```
List<Contact> findByLodgerLodgerIdNot(Long lodgerId);
```

I have a lodger and one contact (who are not associated). When i call this method nothing is returned.

Query generated is

```
    select
    contact0_.contact_id as contact_1_9_,
    contact0_.address as address2_9_,
    contact0_.city_cityId as city_cit5_9_,
    contact0_.contact_sub_category_contactSubCategoryId as contact_6_9_,
    contact0_.first_name as first_na3_9_,
    contact0_.last_name as last_nam4_9_,
    contact0_.phone_phoneId as phone_ph7_9_ 
from
    contact contact0_ 
left outer join
    lodger_contact lodger1_ 
        on contact0_.contact_id=lodger1_.lodger_id 
left outer join
    lodger lodger2_ 
        on lodger1_.contact_id=lodger2_.lodger_id 
where
    lodger2_.lodger_id<>?
```

Edit, i done change asked by JB Nizet

```
select
    contact0_.contact_id as contact_1_9_,
    contact0_.address as address2_9_,
    contact0_.city_cityId as city_cit5_9_,
    contact0_.contact_sub_category_contactSubCategoryId as contact_6_9_,
    contact0_.first_name as first_na3_9_,
    contact0_.last_name as last_nam4_9_,
    contact0_.phone_phoneId as phone_ph7_9_ 
from
    contact contact0_ 
left outer join
    lodger_contact lodger1_ 
        on contact0_.contact_id=lodger1_.contact_id 
left outer join
    lodger lodger2_ 
        on lodger1_.lodger_id=lodger2_.lodger_id 
where
    lodger2_.lodger_id<>?
```

Same result

Edit 2

With this code, that work

```
@Query("select c from Contact c where :lodger not member of c.lodger")
List<Contact> findByLodgerLodgerIdNot(@Param("lodger") Lodger lodger);
```

Instead of use lodger, is it possible to use lodgerId?

That generate this code

```
select
    contact0_.contact_id as contact_1_9_,
    contact0_.address as address2_9_,
    contact0_.city_cityId as city_cit5_9_,
    contact0_.contact_sub_category_contactSubCategoryId as contact_6_9_,
    contact0_.first_name as first_na3_9_,
    contact0_.last_name as last_nam4_9_,
    contact0_.phone_phoneId as phone_ph7_9_ 
from
    contact contact0_ 
where
    ? not in  (
        select
            lodger1_.lodger_id 
        from
            lodger_contact lodger1_ 
        where
            contact0_.contact_id=lodger1_.contact_id
```

Edit 3

```
@Query("select c from Contact c where :lodgerId not member of c.lodger.lodgerId")
List<Contact> findByLodgerLodgerIdNot(@Param("lodgerId") Long lodger);
```

> org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference
>   collection [contact0_.contact_id.lodger] with element property
>   reference [lodgerId]

Comment: Whats in the findByLodgerLodgerIdNot method?

Comment: Spring repository, use name attribute and operation to generate code via it's name. If you have a class user with firstname attribute. you can write a method: findByFirstname(String firstname) and spring will generate code like: select * from user where firstname = ? More info: docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the generated JPQL, your mapping is wrong: Hibernate joins the tables on `contact_id = lodger_id` (and vice-versa), instead of joining them on `contact_id = contact_id` (and `lodger_id = lodger_id`).

That's because you inversed the joinColumns with the inverseJoinColumns. The mapping should be

```
@JoinTable(name = "lodger_contact", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id"), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lodger_id"))
```

Comment: don't seem to be the solution return nothing.

Comment: Then you don't have any contact in the database having at least one lodger that is not identified by the given lodger ID.

Comment: true... Like i said, I have One lodger, One contact. I search the list of contact who are not related to my Lodger.

Comment: But that's now what your query does. It searches for contacts having at least one lodger, which is not the lodger ID. You need the following query: `select c from Contact c where :theLodger not member of c.lodgers`

Comment: i updated, modified your query, that work but would like to know if there are way to avoid to send object to the query.

Comment: Have you tried simply using `em.getReference(Lodger.class, id)` to get a Lodger instance and pass it to the query? `getReference()` doesn't cause any queryto be executed.

Comment: tried getReference, but I see a query is generated.

Comment: It's probably generated when getId() is called by Hibernate when getting the ID to insert as parameter in the SQL query.